# Cannot switch to a file when splitting the view and resizing the files

Tags: vim

I'm relatively new to vim and I'm facing the  issue on  VMware(bionic).

I cannot switch to editor when splitting the view (`:vsp`or `:sp`).

The cursors is placed in newly opened file, but the first file (from which `:sp` is called) is like frozen and also cannot be resized (dashed line between is not dragable). I'm using `.vimrc`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Mouse user:

Add `set mouse=a` in your `.vimrc`. You will be able to switch focus with mouse click, and resize windows by dragging the dash line. See [Focus follow mouse in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712017/focus-follow-mouse-in-vim/13712189#13712189).

#### Keyboard user:

You can type Ctrl-W two times to switch to the next window. Learn more in http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window-move-cursor.

The way to resize window is less convenient as using the mouse. `Ctrl-W >` can increase current window width, and `Ctrl-W +` can increase current window height. See more in http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window-resize

Comment: Yes this works, but previously I didn't have to use Ctrl-W (2 times) I just clicked with a mouse on newly opened file, that is what confused me. But still the files can not be resized?!

Comment: @Anel I have edited my answer to include the way for mouse users.

Comment: So I had already in `.vimrc` `set mouse=a` but few lines after I had `set mouse=r` (as a way to select with mouse and copy-paste outside the vim). When I deleted that line everything works perfectly (in future I can use `shift`+select with mouse to copy-paste outside the vim, but I was wondering is there any way to combine `a` and `r` for example something like `set mouse=ar` (this is not working I already tried) or similar ?

Comment: @Anel How about pressing the shift button when selecting with mouse? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608161/copying-text-outside-of-vim-with-set-mouse-a-enabled